# Update Grouped records

Tags: sql-server, update, duplication

I have the following query that returns duplicate values:

```
  SELECT 
    [t].[Field1], [t].[Field2], COUNT([t].[Field2]) 
  FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [t]
  WHERE [t].[Field2] <> ''
  GROUP BY [t].[Field1], [t].[Field2]
  HAVING COUNT([t].[Field2]) > 1
```

Given that statement, I'd like to write an update statement to clear `Field2` under these conditions.  How would I write this?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this much simpler [using a CTE](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-ctes):

```
;WITH x AS   
(
  SELECT 
    Field1, Field2, 
    c = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Field1, Field2) 
  FROM dbo.Table1
  WHERE Field2 <> ''
)
UPDATE x SET Field2 = '' WHERE c > 1;
```

Or with a more cumbersome (and potentially less efficient, did not test) self-join:

```
UPDATE t SET Field2 = ''
FROM dbo.Table1 AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT Field1, Field2, c = COUNT(Field2)
            FROM dbo.Table1
            WHERE Field2 <> ''
            GROUP BY Field1, Field2
            HAVING COUNT(Field2) > 1) AS x
 ON x.Field1 = t.Field1
 AND x.Field2 = t.Field2;
```

Comment: How do you select from X after the update when using that CTE method? I'm thinking a temp table will be necessary.

Comment: @MichaelZ. Why do you need to "select from X after the update"? You can use the OUTPUT clause but I'd need to understand what you're trying to select and why...

Comment: Yeah I guess you wouldn't need to. I'm just confusing myself. I don't think I've used OUTPUT before so I'll look it up and see if it's useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.  Use a temp table and then inner join:

```
  SELECT [t].[Field1], [t].[Field2], COUNT([t].[Field2]) AS Counted
  INTO
    #TempTable
  FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [t]
  WHERE [t].[Field2] <> ''
  GROUP BY [t].[Field1], [t].[Field2]
  HAVING COUNT([t].[Field2]) > 1

 UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
 SET [Field2] = ''    
 FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [t]
 INNER JOIN [#TempTable] AS [tt] 
    ON [tt].[Field1] = [t].[Field1] AND [tt].[Field2] = [t].[Field2]

 DROP TABLE [#TempTable]
```

Comment: FYI, INNER JOIN and JOIN are the same thing in SQL Server. A little less typing.

Comment: @MichaelZ. For most people, clarity > saving a few keystrokes.